# Check for appearance of (and extract) a numeric value from a string

Tags: java, regex, testing

I am trying to automate a workflow with a Submit button using Selenium in Eclipse.

I am using a custom function `waitForVisible` to check if the `WebElement` with id 'naviInfo' is displayed and if it holds a message having either 'No rows were found' or '{number} rows were found' message.

The problem is I am unable to sort and check the numeric part of the text. Example code given below.

```
String message = waitForVisible(By.id("naviInfo")).getText();

if ("No rows were found".equals(message)) {
      log.info("No rows were found after submit");
}
else if ("**1804** rows were found".equals(message)) {
      log.info("**1804** rows found after submit");
}
else {
      (other error checks)
}
```

How do I just check if there is a numeric value found before the common text ' rows were found'? Additionally also save this number to a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you right, you're just asking how to validate the message matches the expected pattern and how to extract the number from the string? In that case, this has nothing to do with Selenium, but is a simple regex question.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\*{2}(\\d+)\\*{2} rows were found$"); //pattern that says: start of string, followed by two *s, then some digits, then two *s again, then the string " rows were found", and finally the end of string, capturing the digits only
Matcher m = p.matcher("**1804** rows were found");    
boolean found = m.find(); //find and capture the pattern of interest
if (found)
   int count = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)); //get the first (and only) captured group, and parse the integer from it
```

Read up on regex with Java [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: Thanks kaqqao. Your comment really helped me to figure out what I need.

Answer (score 0):

So this is how I made my condition work.

```
if (" no rows were found".equals(waitForVisible(By.id("naviInfo")).getText()))
     waitForVisible(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(),'Nothing found to display.')]"));
else if (Pattern.matches("^ \\d+ rows were found$", waitForVisible(By.id("naviInfo")).getText()))
     waitForVisible(By.xpath("//tbody//tr//td/a"));
else
     other error checks
```